# How to update market data to existing SPL-token?

Tags: share, solana

I made a mistake when uploading market data of Min. Order Size and Price Tick.
This has caused me to be unable to display my trading pair on openbook.

After about 10 minutes of uploading, I can't find my market address in raydium, but Bird's Eye can still see my trading pair.

token address: https://explorer.solana.com/address/Hy2PHBQ4Y7GFHTB5fbSLpB5t6ctqTYC2NzB3W5n15z8u?customUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8899
market address: srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX
Birdeyes: https://birdeye.so/token/Hy2PHBQ4Y7GFHTB5fbSLpB5t6ctqTYC2NzB3W5n15z8u

How can I edit my market data?

This makes me very confused. I would appreciate it if someone could help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to edit market data right now. You will need to create a new market with the correct settings.